# Why does my pin interupt works only once through out the process?

Tags: c, arduino

I have to authenticate a transaction, say a system which will use a pre-fed authentication id to verify any user using the system. The authentication id is supposed to be changed by a super-user using communication through Serial Protocol. Each time a transaction gets completed user has to press a push button to officially finish the transaction and enable super user to feed another authentication ID.
I am able to change the authentication id using Serial event interupt in Arduino, but my pin change interupt is working only once, so I cannot finish the 2nd transaction.

I tried it without using pin change interupt also but, that made a lot of mess in my code and did not work  properly as i wanted, maybe some-thing or some logic I am not able to apply correctly.

```Arduino C language`````

```
void setup()
{
   pinMode(44, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(45, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(46, OUTPUT);  
   Serial.begin(9600);
   //gsm_port.begin(9600); 
   // Turn on the transmission, reception, and Receive interrupt 
   Serial1.begin(9600);    

   attachInterrupt(0, pin_ISR, RISING); //0 here defines pin 2 of Mega2560

}  

 void pin_ISR() //ISR for when box is manually closed a latch gets closed and high value is recvd on pin 2(only pins 2,3 are GPIO interupt pin of Mega2560)//
 {
    b1 = digitalRead(2);
    if(b1==HIGH)
    {
        digitalWrite(44, LOW);
        digitalWrite(45, LOW);
        digitalWrite(46, LOW);
        memset(&fed_id[0], 1, sizeof(fed_id)); //clearing fed_id so that once used cannot be used again till new id is feeded through serial event
     }
 }

void  serialEvent1()  //Serial Rx ISR for feeding new fed_id
{
    while (Serial1.available()) 
    {
      rec = Serial1.read();

        a[i] = rec;
        i++

         }

   }


 void loop()
 {
    char key = keypad.getKey();    

    if (key)
    {
        ///.....some operation here......///
         switch(key)
         { //try implementing shelf not oprning feature if occupied here with each case using 3 IR sensors.
          case '1': digitalWrite(44, HIGH);

                     break; 
          case '2': digitalWrite(45, HIGH);

                     break;
          case '3': digitalWrite(46, HIGH);

                     break;
         }                
    }   
    }//closing for if(key)

}//closing for void loop()
```

If the above is possible without using interupts then too i would love to have a soultion. Please help me to understand why this is not going the right way and also help me finding a solution

Comment: An ISR should _not_ do any I/O like printing. This will upset your system.

Comment: Though I don't know Arduino, an ISR, after servicing the interrupt, should reset the interrupt to indicate the interrupt hardware is ready to receive the next interrupt.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I got your point, now to fix that i'll have to switch to register level may be, not very sure how that will be but I can give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no problem with the code actually and what was discussed in comments that we need to set and reset the interrupt flags/pins, is not the case with Arduino, Arduino does it automatically, while in many controllers we do need to do those things, however the problem here was with the hardware and not any part of code. Just a resistor was creating this problem on Proteus Simulation, however on actual hardware it worked completely fine.